# How to unserialize field before compare by andFilterWhere(['like', ...)

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, yii, yii2

In yii2 I have model with search:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = MyModel::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'passengers', $this->passengers]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

`passengers` is a `TEXT` field in mysql table that contains serialized array.

**Q:** How to tell `andFilterWhere()` function make unserialize and compare by any element from array? Something like this: `$query->andFilterWhere(['like', unserialize('passengers')[0]['name'], $this->passengers]);` - means first element of array with 'name' key

Comment: Query trait methods translate into SQL. presuming by serialized you are refering to phps `serialize()` method, MYSQL has no way of working with that. You need to normalize your database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a gotchya in your data structure. Storing serialized data makes it much more difficult to query. The `andFilterWhere` method only produces SQL level filtering, and you really need code-level filtering as SQL has no idea what PHP Serialization is. There are two ways you could go about solving this:

#### Post Query Filter

Depending on how large your table is, you could return all results of the search query and then use a simple loop to deserialize and drop out values that aren't in your passenger list.

Pseudo code would be:

```
$result = MyModel::search(...);
$filteredResult = array_filter($result->toArray(), function ($el) {
    $availablePassengers = unserialize($el['passengers']);
    return count(array_intersect($availablePassengers, $this->passengers));
});
```

#### Change Your Structure

Probably the best solution would be to change your data structure so passengers are stored in a many-to-many relationship. This would allow you to perform this kind of filtering with a database query and would keep your data properly normalized.